# Mysql Connector/C can't find library

Tags: mysql, sql, c, visual-studio

I install MysqlConnector/C, add in additional include directories MySQL include directory, and add in additional library directories MySQL lib directory (there is no lib/opt directory), and write sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver and get compile error, sql namespace not found.
I have visual studio 2012, and my application is console application (with stdafx.h file). What is problem?